# Активность пользователя

Tags: python

Добрый день.
Мне на python необходимо определять активность пользователя. Подсчитывать количество нажатых клавиш, движение мыши, правый левый щелчек, прокрутка колесика в не окна python программы и т.д.. Нужно для Windows. 
Понимаю что нужно использовать win32 api, а "как и что" ни как не могу найти информацию.
Помогите примером или ссылкой.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: По ссылке http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/developer.shtml есть библиотечка, которая вроде бы умеет то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что надо.

Comment: пример кода для противоположной задачи: [выполнить действие, если пользователь неактивен больше заданного времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572161/23044)

Answer (score 1):

[Из комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/211322/%d0%90%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f/211324#comment211326_211322):

По ссылке cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/developer.shtml есть библиотечка, которая вроде бы умеет то, что вам нужно.

Ещё есть pyautogui и pywinauto модули.