# Отслеживание бездействия Python

Tags: python, распараллеливание, timeout

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать выполнение функции на Python в консольном приложении по таймауту?

Смысл в следующем: Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом и периодически требует от пользователя каких-либо действий. В случае же, если пользователь проявляет бездействие в течение определенного времени, необходимо выполнить определенную функцию.

Из того, что есть:
Функция для отслеживания времени (Пример):

```
StartTime = time.time()  // В теле программе отслеживаем время последнего действия
TimeOut = 2000
def countTime():
   CurTime = time.time() // текущее время
   If CurTime > (StartTime+TimeOut): // проверяем разницу между текущим временем и последним действием, сравниваем с таймаутом
      print SomeFunction() // выполняем необходимую функцию
```

Но я не имею никаких предположений, как запускать функцию проверки времени параллельно (асинхронно?) выполнению основного алгоритма программы.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Думаю после каждого действия пользователя надо хранить точное время его действия в глабальной переменной. Периодически в цикле MAIN проверять чему равняется разница между текущим временем и значением в данной переменной.

Comment: jfs недавно кидал ссылку на [прерывание по signal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1336751/5418360), думаю можно адаптировать (впрочем, там и ещё ответы есть)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> если пользователь проявляет бездействие в течение определенного времени, необходимо выполнить определенную функцию.

Общий подход: запланировать выполнение функции на определённое время и при любой активности пользователя переносить запуск на более позднее время.

Чтобы просто запланировать выполнение функции `func` через 5 секунд в Питоне, не блокируя основной поток:

```
import threading

timer = threading.Timer(5, func)
timer.start()
```

Если `timer.cancel()` (отмена) не вызвать, то через 5 секунд будет вызвана `func()` в фоновом потоке.

Чтобы адаптировать для вашей задачи, необходимо метод `restart()` добавить, который запустит отсчёт заново, при любой активности пользователя. Этот подход достаточно распространён, чтобы своё имя заработать: [Watchdog timer — букв. «сторожевой пёс»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer):

```
watchdog = WatchdogTimer(timeout, func, daemon=True)
watchdog.start()
# ... здесь программа что-то делает
# и перезапускает отсчёт при любой активности пользователя
watchdog.restart()

# в конце отменяем вызов func совсем или просто из программы выходим
watchdog.cancel()
```

где [`WatchdogTimer` класс определён здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115590/4279).

Вот [пример кода, где Питон-скрипт завершается, если пользователь не активен больше заданного времени](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076523/4279) в [X (на Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

---

Необязательно потоки использовать, например, в программе, использующей [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html):

```
async def watchdog(loop, last_activity_time, timeout, func, *args):
    "Run *func(*args)* if more than *timeout* seconds since *last_activity_time*."
    while (loop.time() - last_activity_time()) < timeout:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return func(*args)
```

Цель данной реализации—простота: пока разница между текущим временем (`loop.time()`) и записанным временем последней активности пользователя (`last_activity_time()`) меньше заданного значения (`timeout`), спим. В противном случае вызываем заданную функцию (`func`). Можно придумать решение, которое не использует `asyncio.sleep(1)`.

Пример использования:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import random

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
user = {'last_activity': loop.time()}
asyncio.ensure_future(watchdog(loop, lambda: user['last_activity'], 5,
                               print, 'idle'))
async def simulate_activity():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)
        if random.random() < .1: 
            user['last_activity'] = loop.time() # user have done something now
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
loop.run_until_complete(simulate_activity())
```

Программа печатает `idle`, если пользователь, имитированный с помощью `random` в `simulate_activity()` coroutine, слишком долго не показывает активности.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ!
Утром постараюсь проверить его

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing.pool, threading, random, time
P = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=1)

def timeout_fn(fn: object, *args, __timeout=10, **kwargs):
    '''выполнение функции на Python в консольном приложении по таймауту'''
    f = P.apply_async(fn, args, kwargs)
    return f.get(__timeout)

def thread_fn(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    '''запускать функцию параллельно выполнению основного алгоритма программы'''
    t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    t.start()

def timeout_err():
    print('если пользователь проявляет бездействие в течение определенного времени, необходимо выполнить определенную функцию')

def main(timeout=5):
    while True:
        print('Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом')
        if random.randrange(0, 3):
            print('и периодически требует от пользователя каких-либо действий')
            try:  # выполнение функции на Python в консольном приложении по таймауту
                r = timeout_fn(input, '\tВведите число:\n', __timeout=timeout)
            except multiprocessing.context.TimeoutError:
                print('ERR TIMEOUT %s' % timeout)
                timeout_err()
            else:
                print('[ %s ]' % r)
            finally:
                m = 'запускать функцию параллельно (асинхронно?) выполнению основного алгоритма программы.'
                thread_fn(lambda: print(m) or time.sleep(60))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

out:

```
Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом
Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом
и периодически требует от пользователя каких-либо действий
    Введите число:
123
[ 123 ]
запускать функцию параллельно (асинхронно?) выполнению основного алгоритма программы.
Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом
Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом
и периодически требует от пользователя каких-либо действий
    Введите число:
ERR TIMEOUT 5
если пользователь проявляет бездействие в течение определенного времени, необходимо выполнить определенную функцию
запускать функцию параллельно (асинхронно?) выполнению основного алгоритма программы.
Есть консольное приложение, которое идет своим чередом
...
```